# Rails asset precompile: Invalid CSS in jquery.scrollbar.css background image

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails-4

I am getting the following error during the asset pre-compiling phase of deploying my Rails app:

```
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...round: url(data": expected comma, was ":image/svg+xml;..."
(in  /.../workshop/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
(sass):13673
```

The guilty CSS is the second background definition, which includes a URL for a background image. How can I solve this issue?

```
.scrollbar-light > .scroll-element .scroll-element_size {
background: #dbdbdb;
background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi
8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2
VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkIiBncmFkaW
VudFVuaXRzPSJ1c2VyU3BhY2VPblVzZSIgeDE9IjAlIiB5MT0iMCUiIHgyPSIxMDAlIiB5Mj0iMCUiPgogICAgPHN0b3Agb2
Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iI2RiZGJkYiIgc3RvcC1vcGFjaXR5PSIxIi8+CiAgICA8c3RvcCBvZmZzZXQ9IjEwMC
UiIHN0b3AtY29sb3I9IiNlOGU4ZTgiIHN0b3Atb3BhY2l0eT0iMSIvPgogIDwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+CiAgPHJlY3QgeD
0iMCIgeT0iMCIgd2lkdGg9IjEiIGhlaWdodD0iMSIgZmlsbD0idXJsKCNncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZXJhdGVkKSIgLz4KPC9zdm
c+);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #dbdbdb 0%, #e8e8e8 100%);
```

Answer (score 3):

url need to be quoted ...

```
background: url('data:image/......');
```